# How do I check the value of a field in a mongo database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am creating a Node app that would need to check the fields of a collection and return what the data type is. For example if the field is "First Name" the data type would be "String". How would I get started creating a back end application that does this?

Comment: You need to be more precise in your question. By now I kind of believe that you should just read mongo documentation and for instance mongoose library documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using mongoose , then Each field or nested field is addressed by path.

```
var myschema = new Schema({
  ...
  name: {
       first:{type: String, required: true,},
       last :{type: String, required: true,},
  ...
});
```

here name.first and **name.last are paths**.

Now to know the type of name.last there is an Schema API, called path().So.

```
var pathmeta =  myschema.path(name.last);
console.log(" datatype  = "+pathmeta.instance);
console.log(" whole pathmeta  structure is  "+JSON.stringify(pathmetas));
```

should print this..

> datatype  =  String
>
> whole pathmeta  structure is
>   {"enumValues":[],"regExp":null,"path":"text","instance":"String","validators":[],"setters":[],"getters":[],"options":{},"_index":null}